# Inserting multiple fields with a similar name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form I'm using to send multiple fields with a similar name but using square brackets to send them as an array with the key being 'id'. I am able to loop through successfully using a foreach loop but my insert query fails to make any changes in the db.any clues as to why?

here is the code from the form:

```
$artist = mysql_fetch_array($allartists);
$allmusic = get_music_for_artist($artist_id);
$id = $music['id'];

while ($music = mysql_fetch_array($allmusic)) {
    echo "<td class=\"td20 tdblue\">
        <input name=\"song_title[" . $id . "]\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . $music['song_title'] . "\" />
        </td>"; 
}
```

and here is the code on my form processor

```
foreach ($_POST['song_title'] as $id => $song) {
    $query = "UPDATE music SET 
                song_title = '{$song}' 
                WHERE id = $id ";
    if (mysql_query($query, $connection)) {
        //Success
        header("Location: yourmusic.php?pid=3");
        exit;
    } else {
        //Display error message
        echo "update did not succeed";
        echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . "</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't get an error from mysql_error? Echo the query and tell us what it is? Also, you know after one update the foreach will stop because you've redirected to a new page, right?

Comment: Try doing a `die($query);` before your `mysql_query()` line.

Comment: A few things I want to point out. First, you're vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Make sure you sanitize any user input before using it in a query. Also, you should avoid using `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated. Instead, look into [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php). And, as Jessica pointed out, the loop will only run once if it is successful.

Comment: show $song and $id value example

Comment: the insert works, the problem was with the redirect. thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Also watch for security http://www.phptherightway.com/#data_filtering

```
foreach ($_POST['song_title'] as $id => $song) {
                    $id = (int) $id;
                    $song = mysql_real_escape_string($song);

                    $query = "UPDATE music SET 
                    song_title = '$song' 
                    WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1;";

                    if (mysql_query($query, $connection)) {
                    //Success
                    header("Location: yourmusic.php?pid=3");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    //Display error message
                    echo "update did not succeed";
                    echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . "</p>";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Great, _"security"_ using `mysql_real_escape_string`, a part of a deprecated extension that has a great big yellow box [on the doc-page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) that warns for security issues...